Minimum number of people to satisfy statement
$100$ boys and $100$ girls take an exam. Each boy knows at least one girl and each girl knows at least one boy. Knowing someone is a symmetric relation. After the exam results were announced each girl said that at least $2/3$ of the boys they know got an F on the exam. Similarly each boy said that at least $1/2$ of the girls they know got a C on the exam. It turned out that everyone was telling the truth and the number of boys with an F grade was $10$. What's the minimum number of girls who got a C?
I've tried using a bipartite graph with each of it's vertex sets as the boys and girls respectively connected by edges signifying two people know each other. However I don't know how to effectively translate the inequalities on the number of people with certain grades. If we try coloring the graph we'd need $3$ colors two for the grades and one for a person with an unknown grade. Let $G = (M\cup F, E)$ be a bipartite graph where $M$ and $F$ are (disjoint) sets of vertices representing the boys and girls respectively. Let's denote $\forall v \in F : d_F(v)$ be the number of boys with a grade F that girl $v$ knows. Similarly $\forall v \in M: d_C(v)$ be the number of girls with a grade C that boy $v$ knows. Therefore $\forall v\in F: d_F(v) \ge \left\lceil \frac{2\deg(v)}{3}\right\rceil$ and $\forall v\in M: d_C(v) \ge \left\lceil\frac{\deg(v)}{2} \right\rceil$. I don't know what else I can do from here however. Please help.

We can find the lower bound for the minimum number of girls who got Cs. Each girl can at most know 10 boys who got Fs, since only 10 boys got Fs. In order to maintain the $2/3$ ratio, that means they can know at most 5 boys who didn't get Fs. Since there are 90 boys who didn't get Fs, and every boy knows at least one girl who got a C, there must be at least $90/5=18$ girls who got Cs.
We can check and see that this works as a solution to the problem. Each of the boys who got Fs can know 8 or 9 of the remaining girls, meaning each of them knows one boy who got an F, and none who didn't. Since all the boys who got Fs know all the girls who got Cs, their ratio winds up being $18/26$ or $18/27$, both of which are at least $1/2$. This means that out lower bound is our answer: the minimum is 18.

Very good solution and it doesn't require graph theory at all! I don't know why I was so focused on using a graph to solve the problem when it seems it's not needed at all...
